# Supervisord: is there any way to touch-reload a child?

Tags: supervisord

I'm setting up a server to host a Django app which has:

1. `uWSGI` app started by ubuntu's uWSGI init script
2. `celeryd` started by `supervisord`

So I'm writing a deploy script which will:

1. Pull code from git
2. Migrate the DB
3. Tell `uWSGI` to restart, so it will pick up the new code.
4. Tell `celeryd` to restart, so it will pick up the new code as well.

`uWSGI` has this configuration feature:

```
touch-reload
gracefully reload the uWSGI stack when a file/directory changes.
```

So my script is run by the unprivileged user under which all the app's processes are run.

To restart `uWSGI` I can simply `touch ~/.restart_uwsgi`.

Is there any way I can do the same thing for `celeryd` running under `supervisord` without granting sudo access to the unprivileged user so he can `supervisorctl restart celeryd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I still haven't found a better way to do this, here's what I'm doing right now:

```
# restart_my_proc.sh:
#!/bin/sh
supervisorctl restart <my_proccess_name>

chmod +x restart_my_proc.sh

# sudoers:
<site_user> ALL= NOPASSWD:/path/to/restart_my_proc.sh

# my_deploy_script.sh
sudo /path/to/restart_my_proc.sh
```

So I'm using sudo, not the best solution, but it works.

If someone has a better answer to this, I'll gladly change the accepted answer.

Comment: I think that a tiny Event Listener is a better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227965/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-reload-supervisor-processes/20298885#20298885

Comment: I've seen some django/python dev's using supervisord processes running in userspace instead using the global `/etc/` based setup. that made update/refresh easy.