# Is there a way to automatically reload Supervisor processes?

Tags: supervisord

I have a dev server which I often push code changes to over Git. After each push, I need to manually log into the server and restart the supervisor processes.

Is there a way to have Supervisor monitor a filesystem directory for changes and reload the process(es) on changes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use an [Event Listener](http://supervisord.org/events.html#event-listeners-and-event-notifications) which monitors the filesystem (with perhaps [watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/)) and emits a restart using the [XML-RPC API](http://supervisord.org/api.html). Check out the `memmon` listener from the [superlance](https://github.com/Supervisor/superlance/blob/master/superlance/memmon.py) package for inspiration. It wouldn't need to be that complicated. And since the watchdog would call your restart routine you don't need to read the events using `childutils.listener.wait`.

Alternatively, git hooks might do the trick if the permissions are correct for the supervisord API to be accessed (socket permissions, HTTP passwords). A simpler but less-secure approach.

A simpler and even less-secure approach would be to allow you to issue a `supervisorctl restart`. The running user has to match your push user (or git, or www, depending on how you have it setup). Lot's of ways to have it go wrong security-wise. But for development, might do fine.

Related:

- [Supervisord: is there any way to touch-reload a child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601407/supervisord-is-there-any-way-to-touch-reload-a-child)

Comment: So, this isn't really a solution, more like "how to create a solution."  So now it's nearly 3 years later, is there still no actual solution to what would seem to me to be an extremely common problem?

Comment: It's a real shame that such a heavyweight tool as `supervisord` with so many bells and whistles can't do this simple thing natively.

Answer (score 8):

I also didn't find any solution so I tried to make my own. 
[Here it is](https://github.com/stavinsky/supervisord-touch-reload).

You can install the package by this command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/stavinsky/supervisord-touch-reload.git
```

(I will add it to PyPI after adding some tests. )

An example of setting up supervisor located in examples folder in github. Documentation will be very soon, I believe. 
Basically all you need to start use this module is  add event listener with `command` like:

`python -m touch_reload --socket unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock --file <path/to file file> --program <program name>`

where `file` is a file that will be monitored with absolute or relative to `directory` path, `socket` is the socket from `supervisorctl` section and `program` is program name from `[program:<name>]` section definition.
Also available `--username` and `--password`, that you can use if you have custom supervisor configuration.

Comment: Thanks for publishing this. Seems to work well. Strange indeed that there is no built-in solution for doing something like this

Comment: Welcome. Glad to know that it was helpfull for somebody.  If you will have any issues or ideas how to improve make this script better write me here or on github

Comment: Does this solution only monitor one file at a time?  https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog would let you watch a whole directory.

Comment: The main goal of my module is to restart supervisord job if some file was changed. It is good for example to use with CI.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and created Superfsmon which can do what you want: https://github.com/timakro/superfsmon

```
pip install superfsmon
```

Here's a simple example from the README:

> To restart your celery workers on changes in the `/app/devops`
>   directory your `supervisord.conf` could look like this.
>
> ```
> [program:celery]
> command=celery -A devops.celery worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10
>
> [program:superfsmon]
> command=superfsmon /app/devops celery
> ```

Comment: Does this have any particular advantages over https://github.com/stavinsky/supervisord-touch-reload mentioned in the accepted answer?

Comment: @hackel It has more options like monitoring directories recursively, filtering by file extensions or regex and restarting multiple programs (optionally in supervisor groups). It's probably better documented and on PyPI.

Comment: I've just tried this and it's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

While not a solution which uses supervisor, I typically solve this problem within the supervised app. For instance, add the --reload flag to gunicorn and it will reload whenever your app changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one liner solution with inotify tools:

```
apt-get install -y inotify-tools
```

```
while true; do  inotifywait -r src/ && service supervisor restart; done
```