# Is There any way to update supervisor automatically?

Tags: supervisord

Is there any way to reload the supervisor process every time the code changed,
I want to do it automatically and skip the manual command.

Comment: May you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227965/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-reload-supervisor-processes

Comment: thank you, it's really useful